# Sign CSR with keys in PKCS#12 file using openssl

Tags: openssl, csr, pkcs#12

I wonder if there is a way to sign CSR using keys stored in PKCS#12 file format. This would be nice, since it reduces number of files that need to be stored. Currently I have to keep *.key, *.pem, *.crt and *.p12 files just for this purpose. Of course I quite probably COULD export them from p12 (.pfx) file and use them to sign incoming csr, but I'd rather avoid it. Unfortunately it seems that it is impossible, since the only parameter to "openssl x509" bearing any resemblance to an option that I would use is "-inform" or "-keyform", and nothing except for PEM works for me. Any pointers?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: I have to disagree after looking at results of the following query:

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csr+pkcs12+openssl